# Tomcat 8.5.29 throws EOFException with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: tomcat, 500-error

I'm trying to access spring endpoint in AWS-EKS environment, I'm not recreate this issue locally  but in production logs we see lot 500 Internal Server Error with below EOF Exception logged at same time:

logtype: tomcat-server
message: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.abc.platform.xservices.rest.abcApplication] in context with path [/something] threw exception [org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket] with root cause
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:722)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1072)

Any idea on why we see this in issue in production? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's an internal server error, which returns [status code 500 in response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.5.1)

This may be caused by incorrect requests, but as well server code or overload may be the reason.
If you have access to the server, check event logs.

See also

[500 EOF when chunk header expected](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator/2005Oct/0057)

[Why might LWP::UserAgent be failing with '500 EOF'?](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=543006)

[500 EOF instead of reponse status line in perl script](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/500-eof-instead-of-reponse-status-line-in-perl-script-552805/)

[Apache 1.3 error - Unexpected EOF reading HTTP status - connectionreset](http://objectmix.com/weblogic/552570-apache-1-3-error-unexpected-eof-reading-http-status-connectionreset.html)

[Error 500!](http://modxcms.com/forums/index.php?topic=28473.0)

UPDATE On the other hand, if it's not response message, but a real exception, then it may be simply a bug, [just like in old java](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4191815)
And workaround may be putting getResponseCode() inside of try/catch and call second time on exception:

```
int responseCode = -1;
    try {
        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    } catch (IOException ex1) {
        //check if it's eof, if yes retrieve code again
        if (-1 != ex1.getMessage().indexOf("EOF")) {
            try {
                responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            } catch (IOException ex2) {
                System.out.println(ex2.getMessage());
                // handle exception
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(ex1.getMessage());
            // handle exception
        }
    }
```

Talking by connections number limit, read.

Comment: Thanks Alva, if we use Http 1.1 then by default it uses allowChunking as true.. is there a way to turn it off in tomcat config files? also this issue only happens in prod env and not in non-prod which has same tomcat configurations so its hard to understand. Thanks for your inputs.